# Proof with induction

Tags: induction

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_1,x_2,x_3.....,x_n \in\mathbb{Q}$ with $x_i > 0$ and $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i = 1$

prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \geq n$ (hint:use induction).

Been stuck on that for hours. It seems as if the terminology of the question is not well defiened because they use "Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$" and not "For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$"

Could I get some insight and help please?

Comment: Why must you use induction?

Comment: This is the inequality between the arithmetic mean and geometric mean.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner they hinted it. could you show how to proove it without induction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $a_1+\cdots+a_n \geq n$ if $a_1$, $a_2$, ... $a_n$ are positive real numbers and their product is $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553204/prove-that-a-1-cdotsa-n-geq-n-if-a-1-a-2-a-n-are-positive-real) – the inductive proof is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1553811/42969.

Answer (score 1):

Assume it works with $k$ terms; it certainly does when $k=1$. Consider $k+1$ terms, and permute them so $x_1$ is the greatest and $x_2$ the least. Since by hypothesis the $x_i$ have geometric mean $1$, $x_1\ge 1\ge x_2$. Now consider a sum of $k$ terms, $x_1x_2+\sum_{i=3}^{k+1}x_i\ge k$ by the inductive hypothesis. On the other hand, since $(x_1-1)(1-x_2)$ is a product of non-negative terms we have $$(x_1-1)(1-x_2)=x_1+x_2-x_1x_2-1\ge 0\implies x_1+x_2-x_1x_2\ge 1.$$Finally, $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_i=(x_1+x_2-x_1x_2)+(x_1x_2+\sum_{i=3}^{k+1}x_i)\ge 1+k$$as required.

Comment: First of all, thanks alot for the help!
But could you elaborate some more about the steps that you've taken?

Comment: @trizz See edit.

Comment: Any other elaborations?

Comment: @trizz Maybe you should tell me the first place it's not clear to you.

Comment: I just feel bad for asking you over and over again.

When I tried to solved it, I tried using trichotomy. When $x_n_+_1 = 1 $ the case is obvious. when $x_n_+_1 > 1 $ its also easy. but when $x_n_+_1 < 1 $ its not clear.

Comment: @trizz All you need is that $(x_\max<1\implies\prod_i x_i<1)\implies (\prod_i x_i=1\implies x_\max\ge 1)$, then similarly with $x_\min$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91455/discussion-between-trizz-and-j-g).